# Merge lines that contain word anywhere With line that has this word as first word

Tags: notepad++

I have a text made up of lines which are prefixed by a "key" word and a delimiter "|"

I want to merge the lines that contain this word anywhere to the line that has this word as the first word

Example:

> **large text**|The,first,word,on,some,lines,end,with,this,sign
>
> **other**|texts,below,it,contain,this,word,anywhere,in,the,line
>
> **what is required**|merge,the,lines,containing,this,word،into,the,line
>
> Any text is here then **large text** another word after that
>
> So **other** texts here contain this word anywhere in the line
>
> the end **what is required** to merge the lines

Desired result:

> large text|The,first,word,on,some,lines,end,with,this,sign Any text is here then ***large text#** another word after that
>
> other|texts,below,it,contain,this,word,anywhere,in,the,line So ***other#** texts here contain this word anywhere in the line
>
> what is required|merge,the,lines,containing,this,word،into,the,line the end ***what is required#** to merge the lines

Is there a way to do it in Notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This can't be done in a single pass, you have to click <kbd>Replace all</kbd> as many times as needed.

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(([^|\r\n]+)\|.+$)([\s\S]+?\R)(.+?)(\b\2\b)(.+?$)`
- Replace with: `$1 $4#$5*$6$3`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
(               # group 1
    (               # group 2
        [^|\r\n]+       # 1 or more any character that is not a pipe or linebreak
    )               # end group 2
    \|              # a pipe
    .+              # 1 or more any character but newline
    $               # end of line
)               # end group 1
(               # group 3
    [\s\S]+?        # 1 or more any character, including newline, not greedy
    \R              # any kind of linebreak
)               # end group 3
(               # group 4
    .+?             # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
)               # end group 4
)               # group 5
    \b              # word boundary
    \2              # backreference to group 2, the word to be searched
    \b              # word boundary
)               # end group 5
(               # group 6
    .+?             # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    $               # end of line
)               # end group 6
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to modify the expression replace and make the word located anywhere in the line between these two signs #*
Example:
large text|The,first,word,on,some,lines,end,with,this,sign
Any text is here then large text another word after that
Desired result:
large text|The,first,word,on,some,lines,end,with,this,sign Any text is here then #large text* another word after that

Comment: @amr: Yes it is. Just replace `\b\2\b` with `#\2\*`

Comment: The first expression worked for me, but when modified, it did not find any similarities
What I want is to put the word that is anywhere in the line and similar to the beginning of the line between two tags
Thanks for everything

Comment: @amr: I guess I see what you mean. Change the last part of regex `(.+?\b\2\b.+?$)` into ``(.+?)(\b\2\b)(.+?$)` and the replacement from `$1 $4$3` to `$1 $4#$5*$6$3`.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. I edited the question as required. Can you give me the appropriate expression?

Comment: @amr: I've updated my answer. But it is exactly what I've said in previous comment.

Comment: The expression works for me now
You did a great job, thank you very much
sincerely